# Are Sencha Touch Charts 1 and Sencha Touch 2 incompatible?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

Is Sencha Touch Charts 1 compatible with Sencha Touch 2?

e.g.

I was hoping that this in an html (where `../touch` is the Sencha Touch 2 release):

```
<title>Simple Animation with Sprites</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../touch-charts/sencha-touch-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../touch-charts/touch-charts-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

And `app.js` containing:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Animation',
    requires: [
        'Ext.draw.Component'
    ],
    launch: function() {
        var titleVisible = false;

        var drawComponent = new Ext.draw.Component({
            items: [{
                type: 'circle',
                fill: '#EECC00',
                radius: 100,
                x: 200,
                y: 200
            }]
        });

        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            id: 'panel-container',
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: fit,
            items: [drawComponent]

        });

        drawComponent.surface.renderFrame();
    }
});
```

might give me a circle.

Instead I get an exception on line 339 of `touch-charts-debug.js` indicating that `Ext.util.Observable` does not exist.

Does this mean that Charts 1 is not compatible with Touch 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just announced:

http://notes.sencha.com/post/18941258668/sencha-touch-charts-2-beta-is-now-available-for

Comment: I've edited the code above so it works with this release. Note that it's necessary to pull in the copy of sencha touch 2 that is bundled with the charts beta - otherwise you get exceptions. Also, while this code works, the example in the drawing guide fails to generate an image.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not compatible.

Sencha have said that a beta release of Sencha Touch 2 Charts will be available within a few weeks.

Comment: OK thanks - The Sencha Touch 1 downloads seem to have disappeared from the Sencha site so Touch Charts are in limbo - you can't use them with the available releases.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch 2.1 Beta is now available which supports charts

Here is the link: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/sencha-touch-2.1.0-b2.zip

Release Notes: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/sencha-touch-2.1.0-b2/release-notes.html

Hope it helps you